# getting a nginx 404 when deploying a react app

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, deployment, continuous-deployment, nginx-config

Im trying to deploy a react application onto an ubuntu server. I'm getting a 404 from nginx after I configured my project with github actions and pointed the nginx root to my projects build folder. This is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/zena/actions-runner/app/my-react-app/my-react-app/build;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

This is the file path to my build folder
`~/actions-runner/app/Fresh-Start-Cleaning-Client/Fresh-Start-Cleaning-Client/build`

The build folder does have a index.html file and I havent tampered with it at all